# Call Model from View

Tags: c#, sql, database, model-view-controller

I am having a problem calling a model property from my view. I may have to create an instance of it in the view.

ERROR MESSAGE: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** However inside the model it works fine.

View:

```
@model site.Models.modeldata  
     @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in  Model.DataSets["test"].Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        @:row["id"] 
    }
```

Model:

```
 public IDictionary<string, DataSet> DataSets { get; private set;
```

Comment: You should be passing data from your controller to your view. Use `ViewBag`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be deciding to include the required data for the view. Refactor to use something other than a dataset.

```
//build up a collection in the controller
var items = new List<Customer>();
items.Add(new item{ ID = 4, CustomerName="user123"});
ViewBag.items = items;  //pass to the view via ViewBag, a dynamic object
```

In your view:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.items)
{
    @:item.ID + " " + item.CustomerName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the `DataSets` property in your controller, or better yet, in the constructor of your model. Collection properties shouldn't ever be null unless you have an explicit reason for doing so.

Of course, in this particular case you should also be checking that "test" exists in your dictionary before referencing it.